# Using SCORM with ExpressionEngine

Tags: templates

Is it possible to use SCORM within an ExpressionEngine template? I would really appreciate any advice on this.

A broad overview about SCORM can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharable_Content_Object_Reference_Model

Thanks

The types of data we would want to SCORM are quiz answers (radio buttons and multiple select checkboxes) or numbers of pages visited. Sorry to be vague but we are just starting to look into the option of using EE to deliver content.
The SCORM results would be sent to an LMS.

Comment: Please could you provide some more background about what the SCORM data is, how it's formatted, how you want to display it and so on. This question's currently too vague to answer.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to assist you with this, it's not something I'm familiar with. However without knowing much about SCORM I wonder if Datagrab, http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab, could help? You may also need to have to write your own Add-on as I see no "SCORM" add-ons on devot:ee.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nathan's answer, you're probably going to want to build a add-on module to do the SCORM conversations and tracking, rather than anything frontend. So ideally you'll need PHP/CodeIgniter experience as well as knowledge of SCORM and LMS systems.

ExpressionEngine would be an ideal platform for the creation and management of content and interactions but it would be some overhead to create the SCORM compatibility. I assume you've already considered the likes of [Moodle](https://moodle.org/)? Albeit it's a one stop shop covering everything, including the LMS.

In addition to using EE for the content, the other approach to consider is utilising a JavaScript SCORM API, a quick Google found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673397/is-there-any-free-simple-scorm-2004-javascript-api).

Or convert an [existing SCORM PHP module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498452/scorm-lib-for-php) to CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively no but as ExpressionEngine gives you complete freedom with your front end templates it should be possible to use EE as a tool to create course content. You might also want to look at http://devot-ee.com/search/tags/tag/lms